# android camera with rectangle on the screen

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

It's possible make something like this in my app? screen with native the camera with  green rectangle (it's not watermark).

Picture will be saved without this  green border. green border/rectangle is only for a user, that this part on picture is important.

thx

[image]

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but in my opionion you cant do that with your normal camera app. But its definitely possible programmatically in your own app, done something similar like this before :)

Comment: I will make it in my application programmatically (call camera activity) but i dont know how doing this rectangle ... is an API for this? or i must create any view? I dont know what to look for. thx

Comment: I create a png with that rectangle and transparent background, just  center it above the camera activity!